# Cannot getElementsByName of a website until I inspect it

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am a user of [this website](http://www.baijjt.com/). The reason that I want to get elements of the website is its web design is so inconvenient that I tried to write a script, not manully, to modify some elements' value. But I encountered an issue that I cannot access an element by `getElementsByName("name")` or `getElementById("name")` **UNTIL** I inspect the element by `CTRL + SHIFT + C` in developer mode. BTW, I can't get Elements even after inspecting on `Firefox ESR 78.10.1`.

You guys can tried to see what is the problem. This is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nxDX.png) on Edge Chromium as I try to get the username `<input>`.

As I have researched, some says the page is not fully loaded, but I wrote this js to test if it is loaded.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Bjjt
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http://www.baijjt.com/baijjtcn/RT-e6k7d/*
// @icon         data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
    'use strict';
    window.onload = function () {
        alert(window.onload);
    }
    function myInitFunction() {
        alert("JS is run!");
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", myInitFunction);
    //My goal is to run this ↓↓↓.
    //document.getElementById("ItemQuantity").value = document.getElementById("maxItemQuantity").value;
})();
```

It tells me it is [loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbPnJ.png), but I still cannot run `document.getElementsByName("username")` as it returns a null object.

Could someone tell me what is going on here, I hope you can help me to get started to write my script. Thank you so much!

Comment: Try `DOMContentLoaded` instead of `load` into addEventListener event.

Comment: The page is in an iframe, [look here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_element_iframe.asp) for how you might get around that.

Comment: Were in your HTML file have you loaded the script?, if you place the script before the context your querying, then yes it will return null.  Scripts that need to access the Dom can be placed just before the body closing tag.

Comment: @Keith I run it in console, How can I run it after `body`?

Comment: Oh right, so this is an inspector / debugger issue?  Like mentioned above if it's an iframe until you target it inside the inspector the browser won't know which document to target.  So if you want to do this in code in the browser you will need to also select the iframe in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome, it has a nice feature when using the console if you select an iFrame it will target this for the document.  It looks like in Firefox is does not have this feature.

If your wanting to do this with code you will basically need to do the same thing as Chrome.

Also if you always want to select the same thing, you may also want to do `window.top` to also make sure you always starting from the same place, in case inside the inspect you select another document.

So using this idea, this should do the trick.

```js
window.top    //first start from the main top window
   .document.querySelector('iframe')  //now select the iFrame
   .contentDocument.querySelector('[name=username]') //finally do our selector
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @Cookie  Using the website link you posted it seems to work for me in Chrome, see update answer with screenshot.